# Parsing values from a JSON Python?

Tags: python, json

```
bb_strings = re.findall(r'var model = ({.*})', ad)
bp = {}
if bb_strings:
    bp = json.loads(bb_strings[0])
    for bl in bp['AVAILABLE_SIZES']:
        footlocker.append(('size', bl))
```

out csv:

[IMG 1 CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nO9zZ.png)

How to get output data:
[IMG 2 CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHtaA.png)

Comment: Er yes, you're just printing your own hard-coded string. You don't seem to be accessing the data at all.

Comment: You're defining a string with no input provided and thus it prints nothing. I'd recommend you to read about the json module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: b_string = model['AVAILABLE_SIZES']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 size = 0
 bb_strings = re.findall(r'var model = ({.*})', ad)
 bp = {}
 if bb_strings:
 bp = json.loads(bb_strings[0])
     for bl in bp['AVAILABLE_SIZES']:
     size +=1
     footlocker.append(('size%s' %size, bl))
```

Answer (score 1):

I've cleaned up your json string, because it wasn't valid

```
import json
s = '''{"ALLSKUS":["84664020","07961015","84664113","84664116"],"NBR":"137127","PRICERANGE":"$186.99 - $189.99","GENDER_AGE":"Men's","PRICEADJUSTDATE":"","AVAILABLE_SIZES":[" 07.5"," 08.0"," 08.5"," 09.0"," 09.5"," 10.0"," 10.5"," 11.0"," 11.5"," 12.0"," 12.5"," 13.0"," 14.0"," 15.0"]}'''
j = json.loads(s)
t = j.get('AVAILABLE_SIZES')
print [float(x) for x in t]
```

gives

```
>> [7.5, 8.0, 8.5, 9.0, 9.5, 10.0, 10.5, 11.0, 11.5, 12.0, 12.5, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0]
```

Steps:

- define `s` as string
- load `s` as json object `t`
- get available_sizes from json object
- convert array items to floats (in json string they are strings)

Comment: Must be in the form s = '' '{ALLSKUS: [""], "NBR": "", "PRICERANGE": "", "GENDER_AGE": "", "PRICEADJUSTDATE": "", "AVAILABLE_SIZES": [""]} '' '  ?